# Android reference string from strings.xml without importing package R.java

Tags: java, android, string

In order to reference a string from `strings.xml` I do this:

```
import com.mypackage.myapp.R;

getString(R.string.mystring)
```

It works for a particular project, but that project is a template which I create for other projects. When I do that, my project name is changed hence `import com.mypackage.myapp.R;` becomes invalid as the package name changes too. So, I wonder is there a way to reference a string of the project within the same project without importing project by package name?

**EDIT: In other words I need a package name independent way of obtaining a string resource from strings.xml files which is located in the same package.**

Comment: you can make a class to copy the references from your library to your current project and vice versa.

Comment: @IllegalArgument I don't understand what you mean. I am not a Java developer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Make your template project as a Library project, and in your main project give a reference to your template project, then you can use your resources defined in template project.

Comment: Man project is just a copy of the template project and renames with package and project name.